# Implementing SSL using PHP and .htaccess only

Tags: php, ssl, certificate, hosting

my hosting company is holding me to ransom to pay for SSL

It would seem logical that I can SSL (RSA) encode my site using PHP...

Would this be sufficient to give me the lock symbol?

If not what can I do to add a certificate? can I create one and use it across all my sites?

Comment: You write 'It would seem logical that I can SSL (RSA) encode my site using PHP'. Why? It is impossible. On startup the Webserver binds to port 443 or it doesn't. This is decided in server config before anyone reaches your `.htaccess` or PHP-scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL is 'protocol', it requires 'negotiation of encryption' (send and receive few messages) - not just simple encrypted answer.

PHP code can just send one answer. It can't negotiate (read few requests and send few answers thru one connection).

After successful negotiation, SSL is enabled in web browers, so user also send to you encrypted (safe) request (login/password from forms and everything else is protected). Your server needs to decrypt requests, not only send encrypted answers.

To use SSL you need webserver (hosted by your company) that negotiate encryption and encrypt/decrypt data send by/to web server.

---

If you are looking for free (and weak) SSL protection you can try to use cloudflare.com. They give you 1/2 of SSL (some attacks are still possible - connection between your web company and cloudflare is not encrypted), but they are free. In web browser it will show 'lock' and your website will look like 'secure' website.